# bulk data insert sql issue

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i am importing a huge data from a csv file into my database, but the issue is , if there is a error in the sql , my insertion stops , thus making my bulk insertion useless.i have to go back , delete the uploaded data and remove that entry which is causing issue in my insertion and start again . i want programme to skip it and continue insertion, i know i have to apply try and catch, i have applied it in my algo but i cnt understand how to use so that it continues its insertion .
 here is my code

```
$num=35; //number of columns
$dum=true; // a check
$sum=0;// count total entries

if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['name'], 'r')) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ',')) !== FALSE)
{
    if($dum)
        {
    for ($qwe=0; $qwe < $num; $qwe++) { //searching the columns exact position in case they have been changed 

            if($data[$qwe]=='ID')
            {$a=$qwe;}
            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .else if($data[$qwe]=='PowerMeterSerial')
            {$aa=$qwe;}
            else if($data[$qwe]=='Region')
            {$ab=$qwe;}
            else if($data[$qwe]=='Questions')
            {$ac=$qwe;}

        } 
     }
    if(!$dum)
    {

      for($qwe=0;$qwe<$num;$qwe++)
      { 
           if($qwe==7||$qwe==8)
           { 
           if($qwe==7){$asd=$data[$qwe];}
           $data[$qwe]=date('Y-m-d h-i-s',strtotime($data[$qwe]));
           }
       }


       $data[57]=date('Y-m-d ',strtotime($asd));try { 

        $sql="INSERT INTO pm (ID, .......... Questions, dateofdata ,Unsuccessful) VALUES ('$data[$a]','$data[$b]','$data[$c]','$data[$d]','$data[$e]','$data[$f]','$data[$g]','$data[$h]' ,'$data[$i]','$data[$j]','$data[$k]', '$data[$l]', '$data[$m]','$data[$n]','$data[$o]','$data[$p]','$data[$q]','$data[$r]','$data[$s]','$data[$t]','$data[$u]','$data[$v]','$data[$w]', '$data[$x]','$data[$y]','$data[$z]','$data[$aa]','$data[$ab]','$data[$ac]','$data[57]','$data[30]')";
      if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error(). $sql);
      }

      }
      catch (Exception $e)
      {
     echo'<br>'; echo $sql;
      }
    $sum++;

    }$dum=false;
  }

}
?>
```

**kindly note there is no issue in uploading algorithme or sql , its when input data does not match the data type than sql generates a error , for that i am trying try and catch .. please help**

Answer (score 0):

Change your `die()` command to a `print()`. You'll see what the error was, and the script will move on to the next line.

Given the structure of your code, I'm guessing it'll blow up anytime you're inserting a string (particularly with quotes inside it), causing SQL syntax errors. You **MUST** pass each text field from your csv through [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) BEFORE you insert those values into the query string.

Comment: i have a another algorithme where i have to insert foreign key, but if the inserting value, corresponding value  is not found in the table a error occurs ! i want to continue processing the file !!!